# Unable to fire javascript event OnClick of checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, onclicklistener

So I have a checkbox control that I cannot get to fire an `OnClick` event. I've tried a number of different ways: Binding the event `onload` and adding the event as a parameter in the `<input type="checkbox">` tag.

Here is my most recent iteration of code. I'm trying to fire an `Alert` just to confirm that it changed.

```
<section class="border-bottom">
    <div id="approx" class="content">
        <h3>This is my approximate location</h3>
        <div class="form-control-group">
            <div class="form-control form-control-toggle" data-on-label="yes" data-off-label="no">
                <input type="checkbox"  />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

JavaScript:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').bind('click', function() {
    alert("OK");
})
```

I also wouldn't mind being able to run it via the following input:

```
<input type="checkbox" onclick="runMyFunction(); return false;" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use one of the following methods:

- `.click(function() { ... })`
- `.change(function() { ... })`
- `.on('click', function() { ... })`

HTML:

```
<div section class="border-bottom">
    <div id="approx" class="content">
        <h3>This is my approximate location</h3>
        <div class="form-control-group">
            <div class="form-control form-control-toggle" data-on-label="yes" data-off-label="no">
                <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" />
            </div>
        </div>
     </div>
</section>
```

JavaScript:

```
$('#checkbox').change(function() {
    alert("OK");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Some of the plugins require:

```
$("#checkbox").on('change', function() {
    // content
});
```

or look for the manual of your plugin (sometimes you need to use: `pluginName.change` exchange for change)

Answer (score 0):

First use your jquery function inside $(document).ready function to make sure the dom is ready like :

```
       $(document).ready(function () {
            $('input[type="checkbox"]').bind('click', function () {
                alert("OK");
            })
        });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/4fmL1zfr/8/